# access and serve files outside Apache environment

Tags: php, apache

I need to server files to users via an external link (http://myserver/files/file.zip)
But the files are stored outside of 'Apache environment', in another disk (ex: /dev/sdb1), as we needed a lot of free space. So if I am not wrong we cannot directly link the user to download from there

I am not an IT, so my only idea is that in someway via PHP we have to temporarily grab these files and create a temporary file inside Apache public folders so users can download it. Kind of

```
// Open the file for reading
$handle = fopen($file, 'rb');

// Loop through the file and output it in chunks
 while (!feof($handle)) {
  echo fread($handle, 1024 * 8);
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
```

But the files are quite big (1GB the smaller) and I am afraid this would not be very productive.
Any guidance on that?

Comment: There are _so_ many ways to solve this which do not require any PHP…! Either at the file system level, where you mount the external drive directly into the web root folder, or you simply create a symlink to the drive in the web root folder. Alternatively you can configure Apache to serve specific URLs from the different drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably mount your disk (`/dev/sdb1`) somewhere where you need it.
The command should be something like the below one

```
sudo mount -t /dev/sdb1 /var/yourfoldername
```